# What is the most efficient way of writing [1:20,25:30] in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, numpy

In **matlab**, we can write a list from 1 to 30 excluding 21-24 using `[1:20,25:30]`.
What is the most efficient way of doing that in python?

Another question is, is there a efficient way of removing one element in a list or a column in a **ndarray** in python? Is that the same as in **matlab** by simply setting `A[:,1]=[]` ?

Comment: `alist = [x for x in range(1,21)] + [x for x in range(25,31)]` or just `range(1,21) + range(25,31)` though that may return an "iterataor" in py3

Comment: @Alexander the first will only work in Python 2, and this is tagged 3.x

Comment: If you ever consider writing "Another question" in a post, because you have unrelated questions to ask, you should post multiple questions on this stackoverflow.

Comment: `[x for x in range(1,30) if x <= 20 or x >=25]` or `list(range(1,21)) + list(range(25,31))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB/Octave

```
[1:20,25:30]
```

3 things happen - `1:20`, and `25:30` generate matrices, and the `[   ]` unites them into one matrix.

```
>> [1:20,25:30]
ans =
 Columns 1 through 16:
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
 Columns 17 through 26:
   17   18   19   20   25   26   27   28   29   30
>> A = 1:20;
>> B = 25:30;
>> [A, B]
ans =
 Columns 1 through 16:
    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16
 Columns 17 through 26:
   17   18   19   20   25   26   27   28   29   30
```

The equivalent in `numpy`:

```
In [193]: A = np.arange(1,21);
In [194]: B = np.arange(25,31);
In [195]: np.concatenate((A,B))
Out[195]: 
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30])
```

There are other functions that do the samething, but all end up using `concatenate`, `np.block`, `np.hstack`, `np.r_` etc.  `concatenate` is the basic `numpy` function for joining arrays along one dimension or another.

---

In Python, you can remove elements from a list with a similar syntax:

```
In [201]: alist = list(range(10))
In [202]: alist
Out[202]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
In [203]: alist[3:6] = []
In [204]: alist
Out[204]: [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But that does not work with `numpy` arrays.  They are fixed in size.  The best you can do is create a new list without selected parts.  There is a `np.delete` that does it for you, but it's a convenience rather than a speed tool.

```
In [205]: arr = np.arange(10)
In [207]: np.delete(arr, slice(3,6))
Out[207]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`delete` does various things depending on the removal object.  I think in this case it will copy slices to a new array

```
In [208]: res = np.zeros(10-3, arr.dtype)
In [209]: res[:3]=arr[:3]
In [210]: res[3:]=arr[6:]
In [211]: res
Out[211]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

or maybe just:

```
In [212]: np.concatenate([arr[:3], arr[6:]])
Out[212]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Especially if the removal values are a list, rather than a slice, `delete` uses a `mask`:

```
In [213]: mask = np.ones(arr.shape, dtype=bool)
In [214]: mask[3:6]=0
In [215]: mask
Out[215]: 
array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
In [216]: arr[mask]
Out[216]: array([0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

MATLAB may do some of these things faster by moving more of the action to compiled code.  But the logic will, I expect, be similar.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way in Python is only one character longer if you use a function with a one letter name:

```
l(1,20,25,30)
```

You need to define the function `l` somewhere in your library of utility routines:

```
def l(*args):
    pairs = args[:]
    res = []
    while len(pairs) > 1:
        res += range(pairs[0], pairs[1]+1)
        pairs = pairs[2:]
    assert len(pairs) == 0
    return res
```

- The assert is there to make sure you hand in an even number of arguments.
- The copy of `args` to `pairs` is there to make sure you don't accidently modify a variable handed in to `l`, as in

  ```
  mypairs = [1,20,25,30]
  print(l(*mypairs))
  ```

Comment: Interesting concept of efficiency. Besides, there is really no need to protect args since it is a tuple.